# Java, установка .exe на автозагрузку на win xp

Tags: java, windows

Здравствуйте.

Как программно добавить exe-файл в автозагрузку, если используется win xp?

Comment: Через реестр, например. Или копированием в папку "автозапуск" главного меню.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в автозагрузку файл можно при помощи реестра Windows

Самый простой способ работы в языке java с реестром windows - это с помощью внешних программ, которые уже встроены в данную операционную систему.

```
    package up7;

import java.io.*;

public class Up7 {

    private static void readWinReg (String zn) throws Exception{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;

        try {
            proc = rt.exec("cmd");

        } catch (Exception exc){
            System.out.println("Консоль не запущена");
        }

        BufferedReader bfIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        BufferedWriter bfOut = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (proc.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        int ir=0;
                while ( (ir = bfIn.read()) != 62 )
        {
            System.out.print((char) ir);    
        }

        System.out.print((char) ir);      
        bfOut.write("reg query " + zn + " /s");
        bfOut.newLine();
        bfOut.flush();

                while ( (ir = bfIn.read()) != 62 )
        {
            System.out.print((char) ir);    
        }  
    }

    private static void addWinReg (String zn, String zn2, String zn3) {

   String s = "cmd /C " + "reg add " + zn + " /v " + zn2 + " /t REG_SZ /d " + "\"" + zn3 + "\"";
    try {  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s); }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private static void delWinReg (String zn, String zn2) {
    String s = "cmd /C " + "reg delete " + zn + " /v " + zn2 + " /f\r\n";
    try {  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s); }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
       String rees = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Intel\\Audio"; 
       String rees2 = "name";
       String rees3 = "value";

       addWinReg (rees, rees2, rees3);  
       readWinReg (rees);
       delWinReg (rees, rees2);
       readWinReg (rees);

    }
}
```

[работа с реестром win на Java при помощи reg](http://upread.ru/art.php?id=61)

А также есть возможность работа с реестром win при помощи Java JNA (Java Native Access)

```
public static String getStrRegKey(WinReg.HKEY rootKey, String regKey, String keyName) {
    //создаем основной указатель типа HKEY (хендлер) на ключ реестра,
    // с которым будем работать дальше
    WinReg.HKEYByReference phKey = new WinReg.HKEYByReference();
    //открываем доступ к разделу HKCU - HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    // в данном методе (для простоты) работаем только с этим разделом
    if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegOpenKeyEx(
            rootKey,
            regKey,
            0,
            WinNT.KEY_READ,
            phKey)) {
        //если доступ в раздел получен - получен и хендлер к раздела - phKey

        //заводим парочку необходимых указателей на данные, которые должны получить,
        //обратившись к следующей функции API
        IntByReference lpcbData = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference lpType = new IntByReference();
        //вызываем функцию получения данных по ключу реестра из открытого раздела,
        //но пока только с целью получения информации о наличии этих данных и о
        //типе данных, хранимых там
        if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegQueryValueEx(
                phKey.getValue(),
                keyName,
                0,
                lpType,
                (char[]) null,
                lpcbData)
                ) {
            //если данные есть и тип их строковый - на этот раз запрашиваются
            //реальные данные, которые будут получены в символьном буфере, который
            //резервирует место в памяти под реальный полученный размер информации
            if ((WinNT.REG_SZ == lpType.getValue()) &amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp; ((lpcbData.getValue() &amp;amp;gt; 0))) {
                char[] buffer = new char[lpcbData.getValue()];
                if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegQueryValueEx(
                        phKey.getValue(),
                        keyName,
                        0,
                        lpType,
                        buffer,
                        lpcbData)
                        ) {
                    //если данные благополучно получены - закрываем ключ реестра
                    Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegCloseKey(phKey.getValue());
                    //в приемном буфере лежит нуль-строка, её надо превратить в
                    //"нормальную строку";
                    return Native.toString(buffer);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return "";
}

    public static boolean putStrRegKey(WinReg.HKEY rootKey, String regKey, String keyName, String strValue) {
        //создаем основной указатель типа HKEY (хендлер) на ключ реестра,
        // с которым будем работать дальше
        WinReg.HKEYByReference phKey = new WinReg.HKEYByReference();
        //открываем доступ к разделу HKCU - HKEY_CURRENT_USER
        // в данном методе (для простоты) работаем только с этим разделом
        if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegOpenKeyEx(
                rootKey,
                regKey,
                0,
                WinNT.KEY_WRITE | WinNT.KEY_READ,
                phKey)) {
            //если доступ в раздел получен - получен и хендлер к раздела - phKey
            //записываем пару ключ - REG_SZ значение
            char[] lpData = Native.toCharArray(strValue);
            if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegSetValueEx(
                    phKey.getValue(),
                    keyName,
                    0,
                    WinNT.REG_SZ,
                    lpData,
                    lpData.length * 2)) {
                //для проверки перечитаем записанное
                IntByReference lpcbData = new IntByReference();
                IntByReference lpType = new IntByReference();
                //вызываем функцию получения данных по ключу реестра из открытого раздела,
                //но пока только с целью получения информации о наличии этих данных и о
                //типе данных, хранимых там
                if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegQueryValueEx(
                        phKey.getValue(),
                        keyName,
                        0,
                        lpType,
                        (char[]) null,
                        lpcbData)
                        ) {
                    //если данные есть и тип их строковый - на этот раз запрашиваются
                    //реальные данные, которые будут получены в символьном буфере, который
                    //резервирует место в памяти под реальный полученный размер информации
                    if ((WinNT.REG_SZ == lpType.getValue()) &amp;amp;&amp;amp; ((lpcbData.getValue() &amp;gt; 0))) {
                        char[] buffer = new char[lpcbData.getValue()];
                        if (W32Errors.ERROR_SUCCESS == Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegQueryValueEx(
                                phKey.getValue(),
                                keyName,
                                0,
                                lpType,
                                buffer,
                                lpcbData)
                                ) {
                            //если данные благополучно получены - закрываем ключ реестра
                            Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegCloseKey(phKey.getValue());
                            //в приемном буфере лежит нуль-строка, её надо превратить в
                            //"нормальную строку"
                            String iStr = Native.toString(buffer);
                            //проверяем записанное и прочитанное
                            return (Objects.equals(iStr, strValue));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[работа с реестром win при помощи Java JNA (Java Native Access)](https://ilovejavaforever.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-windows/)

Пути где находится автозагрузка в реестре Windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MASHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CurrentVresion\Run
*\RunOnce
*\RunOnceEx
А так же в ветке HKEY_CURRENT_USER
```

Comment: Все это конечно очень здорово, что вы умеете пользоваться поисковиком, но данный сайт это база знаний. Линки могут быть недоступны или материал на них удален. приведите котороткое описание того что нужно сделать, для решения проблемы в ответе а ссылки оставьте в качестве дополнения.